# Is it safe to remove unused R.* constants from APK?

Tags: android, proguard, android-resources

During splitting app to modules I found that we reached dex fields count limit:

```
D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file. Try supplying a main-dex list.
# fields: 93259 > 65536
```

After the investigation, I found that majority (~67000) of these fields belongs to constants from various `R.java` files.

And with adding new modules this number grows very fast because every module's `R.java` file contains constants from all dependencies.

I found Proguard rule in `proguard-android.txt` that prevents it from shrinking:

```
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
```

So I removed this rule and fields count returned to normal.

Does anyone know why this rule is added to default proguard config and what the consequences would be if these fields are shrunk by Proguard?

Comment: I suspect that allowing changes to `R` would break `getIdentifier()` on `Resources`, a popular way of getting the `R` constant given a string representation of its name. Basically, anything that accesses `R` via reflection may be impacted.

Comment: I looked at sources of `Resources` class and found no reflection at all. It delegates such methods to `AssetsManager` native code where it looks up information from arsc file.

Comment: Also this Proguard rule doesn't preserve `R` class name (only fields inside), so it becomes something like `a`.

Comment: "It delegates such methods to AssetsManager native code where it looks up information from arsc file" -- OK. I'm pretty sure that it used to use reflection, back in the day, but they obviously improved matters since then.